# Specman e: Is there a way to connect a simple_port's hdl_path to negated verilog port?

Tags: specman, e

I have a `signal_map` with reset port. Many environments use this `signal_map` unit. The problem is that the reset port is always active low, but in one environment it is active high. There is already a lot of generic logic for all the environments that refers to the reset port as active low, that I want to use as is.
Can I to connect the port to a negated verilog port (it will solve all my problems)? Something like this:

```
keep reset_port.hdl_path() == not "reset_port_in_verilog";
```

**Additional complication**: The `signal_map` unit already has `hdl_path`, i.e. the actual `reset_port.hdl_paht()` is `"~my_design_module.some_long_path.reset_port_in_verilog"`

What would you do? Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

do you mean that in most of your environments, you would like to have something like

```
event reset is fall(reset_port$);
```

and in one env, have

```
event reset is only rise(reset_port$);
```

?

Comment: Yes, something close

Comment: I have a full SA environment with monitor that has such reset events that is instantiated many times. The top environment only connects the signal_maps of the SA environments.. I cannot overwrite the SA's reset events, since it will change it for all environments... Therefore I don't think that overwriting the events can solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

i think the only solution would be to have different event. maybe something like this -

```
type env_name_t : [ENV_0, ENV_1, ENV_2];

// for most monitors:
unit monitor {
    name : env_name_t;
    !smp : signal_map;
    event reset is rise(smp.reset_sig$);
};

extend ENV_1 monitor {
    event reset is only fall(smp.reset_sig$);
};
```